# Why OpenEBS mount path is still available on host machine even after deletion of PVC?

Tags: openebs

I have deleted PVC, but it shows that OpenEBS mount folder is still present with the PVC folder name and data. This is not releasing space on my host machine. Why it is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenEBS volumes of storage engine (cas type) jiva - use replica pods configured with a hostPath to save the data. Upon deletion of a OpenEBS Volume - the target and replica pods are deleted, but not the associated hostPath and the contents within it. The following issue tracks the implementation of a feature to clean up the contents of the jiva replica hostPath. https://github.com/openebs/openebs/issues/1246

Starting with OpenEBS 0.7, the OpenEBS volumes of cas type - cStor are supported. In case of cstor volumes, the associated data of the volume is deleted when the corresponding PV/PVC is deleted.